# symfony: Format date in assert message

Tags: symfony, datetime, assert

I have assertion on my entity to validate dates. It's work well, but the outuput is formated whith time. I need only the date. (The text is in french)

My entity :

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Assert\DateTime(format="d/m/Y")
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(
 *     value="-2 days",
 *     message="rapports.max_date"
 * )
 */
protected $dateDebut;
```

My translation file :

```
max_date: 'La date saisie doit être inférieur ou égale au {{ compared_value }}.'
```

That output is "La date saisie doit être supérieur ou égale au 1 janv. 2015 à 01:00.". I want "La date saisie doit être supérieur ou égale au 01/001/2015."

I want to format the 'compared_value'. WHo can I do that ?

Comment: What is the value of rapports.max_date?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the `date_format` filter:

```
max_date: 'La date saisie doit être inférieur ou égale au {{ compared_value | date_format('Y-m-d') }}.'
```

Comment: I have tried this, the output is "
    La date saisie doit être inférieur ou égale au {{ compared_value | date_format('Y-m-d') }}". 

{{ compare_value }} is a replacement I think, not a twig variable.

Comment: yes, you are right, `compared_value` is already the replaced string, so date_format has already been applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Write a service and make it globally available to the twig engine.
This service has to define a public function that takes the compared_value, parses the wrongly formatted date, and outputs the correctly formatted one.

So:

```
class MyService 
{
    public function parse($compared_value) {
        return date_format('Y-m-d', strtotime($compared_value));
    }
}
```

in config.yml

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_service: '@my_service'
services:
    my_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
```

and finally

```
max_date: 'La date saisie doit être inférieur ou égale au {{ my_service.parse(compared_value) }}.'
```

Comment: I have tried, but the problem is the same as used "{{ compared_value | date_format('Y-m-d') }}". The variable {{compared_value }} is replace without twig, it's replace in PHP.

Comment: I Have found where the date is build, it's build in ConstraintValidator.php:108 and it's static ...

Comment: Still my solution should work. You can apply any function in twig as long it is available from a service. The parse function first converts the date string to a dat object and then reformats it to a string using your preferred format.

Comment: I am ok with you, but symfony replace the string in php, not in twig. lAnd I think, it's not possible to use twig function in translation file. .